# conectar Zoho con React js pero me esta siendo imposible alguna idea?

Tags: reactjs

Alguien habra logrado hacer la conexion para crear un widget? se que puede hacerse por api o por sdk péro no eh logrado conectarlo de ninguna de las formas si alguien a tenido un problema similar y desea compartir me haria un gran favor

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un repro de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.